# Sharepoint designer won't connect to localhost

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, iis

I use IIS 6 with windows7

I installed Sharepoint Designer 2007. `http://localhost` is functioning allright.

Now my problem:

When in SharePoint Designer I try to open `http://localhost` I get the error message that the folder name is not valid. Same error when I use the local IP number in stead of localhost.
How solve this problem?

Comment: check this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/898c50f8-3fa2-4b35-b7e6-5a6c553dcc8a/opening-a-sharepoint-site-in-spd-folder-name-is-not-valid?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: what sharepoint version you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction
I am using sharepoint designer 1007
Alwin

Comment: What is the version of the SharePoint environment you have set up? Is this SharePoint environment running locally on your computer?

Comment: Check that you can open the target site with Internet Explorer. If IE can't open the site then neither can SPD and it will throw the folder name error.